# Making the status bar background transparent

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, uistatusbar

Hi I am pretty new to iOS development. I needed to hide the white bar that appears under the status bar. I tried out solutions but could not really get it to work. What is the simplest solution to do this? Is there something that I can do in the app delegate? I want the map to be under the status bar, like the Uber application. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: The status bar is transparent by default.

Comment: Maybe There is an issue with Storyboard CONSTRAINT.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this: (UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView)?.backgroundColor = .clear